Retrieve Dropbox Token in a Google Sheets Script
I am trying to retrieve a Dropbox Token without having to manually generate it. I found various competing approaches to doing this in a Google Sheets Apps Script.  I have come perilously close, but I keep hitting a stumbling block which I don't understand and can't fix.
Let me provide some context:
I have a dropbox account.  I have created a app called GK_NMX_GetFileList.  I believe the permissions are set correctly. As a result, I have an account ID and a secret ID. I got the script from a sample posted and now can't find it.   Here is the script:
function getDropboxAccessToken_test() {
  var REDIRECT_URI = 'https://script.google.com/macros/d/1qF01ii0esrwCSL7j2xwz342MLEjsbEjrLMnLA3eWVWQYgpVr2VEw-Hwv/usercallback'; 
  var CLIENT_ID = '**NOTSHOWNHERE**'; // I took this out from here for safety reasons
  var authUrl = 'https://www.dropbox.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=' + CLIENT_ID + '&response_type=code&redirect_uri=' + REDIRECT_URI;
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<a href="' + authUrl + '" target="_blank">Click here to authorize access to Dropbox</a>.');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'Authorize Dropbox Access');
}

function usercallback_test(request) {
  try {
    var code = request.parameter.code;
    var CLIENT_ID = '**NOWSHOWNHERE**'; // I took this out from here for safety reasons
    var CLIENT_SECRET = '**NOTSHOWNHERE**'; // I took this out from here for safety reasons
    var REDIRECT_URI = 'https://script.google.com/macros/d/1qF01ii0esrwCSL7j2xwz342MLEjsbEjrLMnLA3eWVWQYgpVr2VEw-Hwv/usercallback'; 
    var payload = {
      'code': code,
      'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
      'redirect_uri': REDIRECT_URI,
      'client_id': CLIENT_ID,
      'client_secret': CLIENT_SECRET
    };
    var options = {
      'method': 'post',
      'payload': payload
    };
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://api.dropbox.com/oauth2/token', options);
    var data = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
    if (data.error) {
      throw new Error('Error exchanging code: ' + data.error_description);
    }
    var accessToken = data.access_token;
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Auth_NMX');
    if (!sheet) {
      throw new Error('Sheet "Auth_NMX" not found.');
    }
    sheet.getRange('D12').setValue(accessToken); 
  } catch (e) {
    Logger.log('Error in usercallback: ' + e.message);
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Error: ' + e.message);
  }
}


My understanding is that this script will get a new token and place it in cell D12 in the Auth_NMX sheet in my workbook.
I have taken pains to make certain that the redirect UPI in the script above is also stored in the URI section of the Dropbox parameters:
https://script.google.com/macros/d/1qF01ii0esrwCSL7j2xwz342MLEjsbEjrLMnLA3eWVWQYgpVr2VEw-Hwv/usercallback
So here's the issue -- when I run this function (which I kick off with in the Google sheet seeking to retrieve the token) this is what happens:

The first part of the script appears to execute
I then get a screen inside the google sheet which prompts me to "Authorize Dropbox Access" and says "click here to authorize dropbox access"
When I click on that link, it returns an error with the following URL: *https://script.google.com/macros/d/1qF01ii0esrwCSL7j2xwz342MLEjsbEjrLMnLA3eWVWQYgpVr2VEw-Hwv/usercallback?code=REDACTED - which says "Sorry, unable to open the file at this time.
Please check the address and try again."

I am stymied and have no idea what is going on here and am very anxious to successfully retrieve the token an dplace it in my sheet.  Please help!
Everything is clarified in my note above.

It's not a good idea to roll your own implementation of oauth. Use https://github.com/googleworkspace/apps-script-oauth2

Also there's a readymade sample for Dropbox in the samples folder there.

Could I impose on you to provide the URL or name of the example in GItHub in the samples folder to which you refer?  I'm stymied by the sheer number of entries there and candidly am not familiar enough with this stuff ... I'm something of a neophyte in this space (as you can tell!)   I appreciate it!

https://github.com/googleworkspace/apps-script-oauth2/blob/main/samples/Dropbox.gs

BTW, that code I redacted is important information. Since it is exposed, you might wanna change your credentials in Dropbox, deauthorize authorized apps as needed.
